# I get error "Failed to Receive" when i use mail() in php

Tags: php, email

```
$strBody="<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 align=center border=1><TR><TD align=left valign=top><font face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color='#000000' size=2>Name</font></TD><TD colSpan=2><font face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color='#000000' size='1'>".$_SESSION['fname']."   ".$_SESSION['lname']."</font></TD></TR>";
//$strBody="good".$strBody;
$strBody=$strBody."<TR><TD align=left valign=top><FONT face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color=#000000 size=2>Topic</FONT></TD>";
$strBody=$strBody."<TD colSpan=2 align=left valign=top><font face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color='#000000' size='1'>".$_SESSION['topic']."</font></TD></TR>";
        $strBody=$strBody."<TR><TD align=left valign=top><FONT face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color=#000000 size=2>Detail of Topic</FONT></TD>";
        $strBody=$strBody."<TD colSpan=2 align=left valign=top><div align=justify><FONT face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color=#000000 size=1>".$_SESSION['detail']."</FONT></div></TD></TR>";
        $strBody=$strBody."<TR><TD align=left valign=top><FONT face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color=#000000 size=2>Broad Category</FONT></TD>";
        $strBody=$strBody."<TD colSpan=2 align=left valign=top><FONT face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color=#000000 size=1>".$_SESSION['Head']."</FONT></TD></TR>";
        $strBody=$strBody."<TR><TD align=left valign=top><FONT face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color=#000000 size=2>Your Educational Level</FONT></TD>";
        $strBody=$strBody."<TD align=left valign=top><FONT face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color=#000000 size=1>".$_SESSION['reqfor']."</font></TD></TR>";
        $strBody=$strBody."<TR><TD align=left valign=top><FONT face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color=#000000 size=2>Desired Size</FONT></TD>";
        $strBody=$strBody."<TD align=left valign=top colSpan=2><FONT face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color=#000000 size=1>".$_SESSION['dsize']." page(s), ".$_SESSION['nofwords']." Words.</font></TD></TR>";
        $strBody=$strBody."<TR><TD align=left valign=top><FONT face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color=#000000 size=2>Dead Line</FONT></TD>";
        $strBody=$strBody."<TD colSpan=2 align=left valign=top><FONT face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color=#000000 size=1>".$_SESSION['deadline']." (".$_SESSION['deadlinedate'].")</font></TD></TR>";
        $strBody=$strBody."<TR><TD align=left valign=top><FONT face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color=#000000 size=2>Type/Format</FONT></TD>";
        $strBody=$strBody."<TD colSpan=2 align=left valign=top><FONT face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color=#000000 size=1>".$_SESSION['typeformat']."</font></TD></TR>";
        $strBody=$strBody."<TR><TD align=left valign=top><FONT face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color=#000000 size=2>Style of Report / Style of Citation</FONT></TD>";
        $strBody=$strBody."<TD colSpan=2 align=left valign=top><FONT face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color=#000000 size=1>".$_SESSION['stylereport']."</font></TD></TR>";
        $strBody=$strBody."<TR><TD align=left valign=top><FONT face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color=#000000 size=2>Your Email</FONT></TD>";
        $strBody=$strBody."<TD colSpan=2 align=left valign=top><FONT face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color=#000000 size=2><a href='mailto:".$_SESSION['email']."'>".$_SESSION['email']."</a></TD></TR>";
        $strBody=$strBody."<TR><TD align=left valign=top><FONT face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color=#000000 size=2>Alternate Email</FONT></TD>";
        $strBody=$strBody."<TD colSpan=2 align=left valign=top><FONT face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color=#000000 size=2><a href='mailto:".$_SESSION['aemail']."'>".$_SESSION['aemail']."</a></TD></TR>";
        $strBody=$strBody."<TR><TD colSpan=3></TD></TR></TABLE>";
        $strBody=$strBody."</TABLE></form>";

echo $strBody;
$to= $_SESSION['email'];
$from = "**********";
$subject = "Testing mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
echo mail($to,$subject,$strBody,$from);
```

if i use $strBody i get error...if i use $message the code works fine. I have display $strBody and it shows up fine but when i try to use it in mail() i am getting error.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to Receive in D:\*****.php on line 67

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [PHP Manual for mail()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), the lines in the message must be 70 chars long max. and should be separated with \n (LF). While I've never encountered a problem caused by this, you can give it a try.

Oh, I generally write down message HTML in a single string like:

```
$message = '
    <div>
        <span>...
        ...etc...
        ';
```

So it's getting newlines automatically. You can simply trim `$strBody=$strBody."` parts and concatenate the message into a single multiline string.

If you can't get it working, you can try ready-made classes like [Zend Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mail.introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

`$to= $_SESSION['email'];`
Are you sure that your session contains correct e-mail address? Try to debug it. Maybe you forgot `session_start` before any output?