# Warning: mail(mail.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in

Tags: email, smtp, php

I am trying to use the function mail in a server over windows with iss7 and i am getting this warning which doesn't let me send mails:

```
Warning: mail(mail.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in xxxx
```

That line is:

```
mail("mail@myserver.com", "subject", 'body',"From: mail2@myserver.com")
```

At php.ini i have configured SMTP server, port and sendmail_from like this:

```
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = 128.x.x.xxx
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 110

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = mymail@myserver.com

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
mail.log = mail.log
```

I have also created a file called "mail.log" inside C:/php/ and i have changed permissions to write and read for all users.

Also, at **phpinfo**() safe_mode is **Off**.

I am currently sending mails with PHPMailer but it is soooo slow that i want to try it with mail function.

Do you know what am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the line of your mail function? That doesn't look right to me.

Comment: The line of the error is the line in which i use the mail function, i will upload the question in a few seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a `mail.log` entry in your `php.ini` file which should log all the `mail()` function calls. Search for it and if you don't have this line, then it's taking some strange default or previously defined value, so you better define it and point it to the file you have created in your PHP folder and hopefully assigned good permissions to. For more check what `phpinfo()` is saying about mail.log.

For more info: [mail configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.mail.log).

Comment: I updated my post. I already have that line. Take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Then explicitly define it to `"C:\php\mail.log"` or whatever your file is called. Eg. `mail.log = "C:\php\mail.log"` or `mail.log = "C:/php/mail.log"`

Comment: Ok, i have changed as you said and i restarted the server and it has improved. Now i get this message: Warning: mail(): Failed to Receive in xxx (same line)

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084932/i-get-error-failed-to-receive-when-i-use-mail-in-php

Comment: I already did it. But my line is almost exactly as the one i posted as i am testing it. Is not a problem of the number of characters.

Comment: What if you completely remove the `mail.log` line?

Comment: Then I still having this last warning. Warning: mail(): Failed to Receive in xxx

Comment: I have opened another questions for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461692/warning-mail-failed-to-receive-in