# Warning: mail(): Failed to Receive in

Tags: email, smtp, php

I am trying to use the php mail function on my windows server over ii7 and i am having this warming which doesn't allow me to send mails.

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to Receive in xxx
```

That line contains this:

```
mail("mail@myserver.com", "subject", 'body',"From: mail2@myserver.com")
```

At php.ini i have configured SMTP server, port and sendmail_from like this:

```
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = 128.x.x.xxx
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 110

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = mymail@myserver.com
```

**phpinfo**() safe_mode is **Off**.

What can be the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: How large is your body content? Perhaps try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084932/i-get-error-failed-to-receive-when-i-use-mail-in-php

Comment: The same as the one i have on the question. I am just testing it so it is not a problem of the number of characters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084932/i-get-error-failed-to-receive-when-i-use-mail-in-php, https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=13634

Comment: `110` is a POP3 port, not SMTP. Try `smtp_port = 25` instead.

Comment: That's it @DaveRandom!! Thanks! Post it as a reply to value it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`110` is a POP3 port, not SMTP. Try `smtp_port = 25` instead.